# Asp.net adding strings to the end of the url, probably session related

Tags: asp.net, url

When I click on one of the links on the menu it goes to the page url for example:

http://www.url.com/my-page.aspx

but just after it gets there it adds a string to the end and it looks like:

http://www.url.com/my-page.aspx#.T8eVgMWxmHM

or

http://www.url.com/my-page.aspx#.T8eVuNXSoR8

My guess is that it got something to do with the sessions, any ideas on how to get rid of it?

Comment: the symbol `#` is for move the focus to a line of the page. This number can not be readed on code behind, so nothing to do with session

Comment: This is an anchor tag to help you keep focus at a height point on the page.  What Control are you using?  It might have a setting to turn this feature off.

Comment: True, found it, another programmer added a Social Media Widget, and that was causing it with a script!, I was looking on the wrong place :) thanks for the guidance guys!

Answer (score 0):

This symbol `#` on the url is used for make the browser to make visible and top of the page a link with this code inside the html document.

For example if you place inside your page

```
<a name="tips">Useful Tips Section</a>
```

and make a link on the url as

```
urlpage.aspx#tips
```

then the browser bring on top the line of the page that have the line "Useful Tips Section". So nothing with viewstate. Also what is after the # can not be readed on code behind.